# why is my windows system not booting

Tags: windows-7

i just tried to start my system and am can only see a black screen that says TFGHT is compressed. Press ctrl+alt+del to restart.
this happens every time I press the keys or boot manually.
what can be the issue?

Comment: Are you sure you're on the right site ?

Comment: Can you suggest the right site?

Comment: According to multiple links from google searching for tfght is compressed. It appears that the easiest way is to use the recovery disk
Start your computer from the Windows 7 installation DVD or Repair CD.
click Repair your computer.
load driver. Go to Computer and right click drive where Windows 7 is installed. Under Properties and uncheck "Compress drive to save disk space". Exit and restart the computer normally.